# Clang-cl fails to build NSS lib due to emmintrin.h even with -msse2 flag

Tags: c++, c, clang, sse2, nss

The freebl library in NSS fails to build properly (as a part of Firefox) due to emmintrin.h header from Clang 3.7 throwing errors that I'd assume were due to a missing -msse2 flag. Even with this flag, the source file that calls this header fails.

```
14:08.94 d:/gecko-dev-release/security/nss/lib/freebl/intel-gcm-wrap.c(123,78) :
  error(clang): passing 'int' to parameter of incompatible type '__m128i' (vecto
r of 2 'long long' values)
14:08.94     _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)gcm->CTR, _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_add_epi32
(ONE, _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)gcm->CTR), BSWAP_MASK)), BSWAP_
MASK));
14:08.94
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
14:08.94 c:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.0\include\emmintrin.h(630,36
) :  note(clang): passing argument to parameter '__b' here
14:08.94 _mm_add_epi32(__m128i __a, __m128i __b)
14:08.94                                    ^
14:08.94 1 error generated.
14:08.96 intel-gcm-wrap.c
14:08.99 d:/gecko-dev-release/security/nss/lib/freebl/intel-gcm-wrap.c(123) : er
ror C2164: '_mm_shuffle_epi8' : intrinsic function not declared
14:08.99 d:/gecko-dev-release/security/nss/lib/freebl/intel-gcm-wrap.c(123) : er
ror C2284: '_mm_shuffle_epi8': illegal argument to intrinsic function, parameter
 1
14:08.99 d:/gecko-dev-release/security/nss/lib/freebl/intel-gcm-wrap.c(123) : er
ror C2284: '_mm_shuffle_epi8': illegal argument to intrinsic function, parameter
 2
14:08.99 d:/gecko-dev-release/security/nss/lib/freebl/intel-gcm-wrap.c(123) : er
ror C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from '' to '__m128i'
14:08.99 clang-cl.exe: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 2 (us
e -v to see invocation)
14:09.00 ../../coreconf/rules.mk:384: recipe for target 'd:/gecko-dev-release/ob
jdir/security/nss/lib/freebl/intel-gcm-wrap.obj' failed
14:09.00 mozmake.EXE[7]: *** [d:/gecko-dev-release/objdir/security/nss/lib/freeb
l/intel-gcm-wrap.obj] Error 2
14:09.00 Makefile:568: recipe for target 'libs' failed
14:09.00 mozmake.EXE[6]: *** [libs] Error 2
14:09.00 Makefile:468: recipe for target 'libs-nss/lib/freebl' failed
14:09.00 mozmake.EXE[5]: *** [libs-nss/lib/freebl] Error 2
14:09.00 mozmake.EXE[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
14:11.30 d:/gecko-dev-release/config/recurse.mk:74: recipe for target 'config/ex
ternal/nss/target' failed
14:11.30 mozmake.EXE[4]: *** [config/external/nss/target] Error 2
14:11.30 d:/gecko-dev-release/config/recurse.mk:36: recipe for target 'compile'
failed
14:11.30 mozmake.EXE[3]: *** [compile] Error 2
14:11.30 d:/gecko-dev-release/config/rules.mk:541: recipe for target 'default' f
ailed
14:11.30 mozmake.EXE[2]: *** [default] Error 2
14:11.30 d:/gecko-dev-release/client.mk:400: recipe for target 'realbuild' faile
d
14:11.30 mozmake.EXE[1]: *** [realbuild] Error 2
14:11.31 client.mk:171: recipe for target 'build' failed
14:11.31 mozmake.EXE: *** [build] Error 2
14:11.36 0 compiler warnings present.
```

You can browse the source directory [here](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/nss/lib/freebl).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [clang internals manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html):

> `__extension__`: The expression form of this extension causes any evaluatable subexpression to be accepted as an integer constant expression.

If we take a look at [the current definition that clang has for `_mm_suffle_epi32`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Headers/emmintrin.h#L1318) it becomes clear that this is described above as an "integer constant expression"s.

Looking through the history for that function-like macro, it seems it was modified to use the `__extension__` keyword in order to ["Fix vector macros to correctly check argument types"](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/32bae37b821e6ade738849ac14e3d3de06afb0be#diff-622fb690338524ce355edd36238ead5dL1262), and then that change was over time virtually rolled back as you can see from the current definition.

In summary, it seems like this is a Clang library error. `_mm_shuffle_epi32` isn't the most documented feature on the planet, but the research I turned up implied that it should result in an `__mm128i`. Perhaps, if they wish to correctly check argument types, they should declare this as a [inlined?] function, rather than a macro?

When I tried to engage in a discussion about this on various IRC channels, nobody responded, so... I thought I'd just put this here for you as an answer to your question, because it's too lengthy for a comment.